# Firestore Update Inside Array of object

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a structure like this and in this I want to update the role of userId '2' to "Admin".

```
{
  "chats": {
    "chatThreadID": {
      "chatUsers": [
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "role": "Admin"
        },
        {
          "userId": 2,
          "role": "General"
        },
        {
          "userId": 3,
          "role": "General"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried doing  'updateData'

```
"chatUsers": FieldValue.arrayRemove([oldUser.dictionary])
```

Then

```
"chatUsers": FieldValue.arrayUnion([updatedUser.dictionary])
```

This works, but is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing looks correct to me.

If you're looking to update a user with a single write operation, the most common alternative is to not store the users in an array field with their roles, but store the user+roles in a map field:

```
"chatUserRoles": {
  "1": "Admin",
  "2": "General",
  "3": "General"
}
```

With this structure, you can update a specific user with dot notation:

```
"chatUserRoles."+updatedUser.dictionary.userId: updatedUser.dictionary.role
```

Or as literal text:

```
"chatUserRoles.1": "General"
```

Comment: How to use "chatUserRoles."+updatedUser.userId: updatedUser.role?

Comment: I updated the code in my answer to include the `.dictionary` that you're using, and also to show it without the variables. It's meant to be the replacement of your current line of code to update the document. If it isn't working for you, show what you tried and what the result was.